# Oracle Insert all data from another table with one column as null

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have two tables A and B both same structure except B has one addition extra column. I need to Retain all data from A in B but the extra column should set as null. How to do this. Please help.

```
Table A:
    id VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL, 
    effectiveDate DATE, 
    endDate DATE, 
    startDate DATE, 
    Type NUMBER(9), 
    salary NUMBER(19,3), 
    baseSalary NUMBER(19,3), 
    Amount NUMBER(19,3), 
    Amount1 NUMBER(19,3), 
    currency NUMBER(9), 
    Percentage NUMBER(20,9), 
    Salary NUMBER(19,3) 


Table B

 id VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL, 
    effectiveDate DATE, 
    endDate DATE, 
    startDate DATE, 
    Type NUMBER(9), 
    salary NUMBER(19,3), 
    baseSalary NUMBER(19,3), 
    Amount NUMBER(19,3), 
    Amount1 NUMBER(19,3), 
    currency NUMBER(9), 
    Percentage NUMBER(20,9), 
    Salary NUMBER(19,3),
    Notional NUMBER(9) -- This is the new column need to set as null
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two columns names `salary` in your table?

Comment: @Ollie they are two: a big salary and a small salary. If you not obeye you'll get the small one :P

Comment: its duplicated need to remove

Answer (score 0):

```
insert
  into tableB(
         id,          effectiveDate, endDate
        ,startDate,   Type,          salary
        ,baseSalary,  Amount,        Amount1
        ,currency,    Percentage,    Salary
        ,Notional
       )
select   id,          effectiveDate, endDate
        ,startDate,   Type,          salary
        ,baseSalary,  Amount,        Amount1
        ,currency,    Percentage,    Salary
        ,null
  from tableA;
```